# How do I early stop my model training in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I want to stop my model training in Keras as soon as the accuracy 'acc' reaches a certain value, in my case 0.9. I wanted to apply the EarlyStopping callback but did not succeed yet. I thought that the following would suffice:

```
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
            monitor = 'acc',
            verbose = 2,
            mode = 'max',
            baseline = 0.9
    )
```

Training stops after one epoch at an accuracy of 0.34 without any notice (thought verbose = 2). I tried to add a min_delta = 0.1 in the expectation that this rule would only be applied after the baseline was reached, but that did not help. The manual says that:

> baseline: Baseline value for the monitored quantity to reach. Training will stop if the model doesn't show improvement over the baseline.

and

> mode: one of {auto, min, max}. ... in max mode it will stop when the quantity monitored has stopped increasing...

From previous runs I know my model is increasing to 1.00 in about 25 epochs. Why does it stop so early without any notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me your line works like expected. Since you did not provide a [minimal workable example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) it is probably the easiest, if you debug the issue yourself. It is actually quite easy.

Add this line right before your call to `model.fit` and run your code:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

You will now get the ipdb-prompt. Type this:

```
ipdb> b EarlyStopping.on_epoch_end
ipdb> c
```

Now your program should run until it reaches the breakpoint. Now you can step through the code using `n` to advance a line and you can use `p` print variables. Here is an example to check, what is the current best accuracy and what is the new value for the current epoch:

```
    543         if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best):
--> 544             self.best = current
    545             self.wait = 0

ipdb> p self.best
0.9
ipdb> p current
0.9196166666348775
```

This way you can check, which path through the code is taking and where it deviates from what you expect. If that is not sufficient to solve your problem the additional information will definitely be helpful for others do help you solve your problem.

**Update**:
You are correct. It does not actually work as expected. It just happen to stop at the right time in my test I did. But using the original class as a template it's easy to create your own class so that you get this behaviour:

```
class CustomEarlyStopping(EarlyStopping):
    def __init__(self, threshold):
        self.threshold = threshold
        super(CustomEarlyStopping, self).__init__(monitor='acc')

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current = self.get_monitor_value(logs)
        if current is None:
            return

        if current >= self.threshold:
            self.stopped_epoch = epoch
            self.model.stop_training = True
```

Comment: +1 for showing ipdb. Didn't know I could call it programmatically. Looking at the code in callback.py lines 538-540: what I want seems not possible: to wait until a limit is reached. I am surprised it worked for you. Do we have the same versions of keras? I got 2.2.2

Comment: I just did the same and that worked great! Thanks for suggesting this answer so I can mark your answer as correct. It remains a strange piece of keras  code though: it does not work as I understood from the manual. Anyway: your answer helped me too find what I should do. Thanks!

Comment: I think the baseline option is only intended to catch cases where the network is worse than random which means something fundamentally is wrong.

Comment: That might be the case but I didn't gather that from the manual. Anyhow I decided to make it an issue in Keras: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11496